# Creating Deal for Percentage of App Sales

Tags: contract

I have a business partner who wants to do a deal where I will get a percentage of the profits from app sales. I like the deal and want to do it. In our business agreement I want to put some language that defines what happens as the project moves forward - for example, what if he wants app updates that I don't think are necessary? What if he wants to work with a different developer in the future, but wants to use the code that I developed?

Answer (score 1):

You are taking all the risk of this project (e.g. won't get paid if it fails) and in that case you should get a percentage in ownership of this project/business, and I don't know how much percent in ownership would be fair, probably it depents on what's your partner part in this project. Think about what you are investing into this project (your time and knowledge) and what's your partner is investing (hope is not just an idea).

Answer (score 0):

This is why you need at least a contract:  you have to have these things agreed in advance.  Having things spelled out, even if not really to your advantage, beats litigation.  (Another thing to consider:  what if you don't think he's putting enough effort into selling the apps?)

For this, you consult a lawyer with appropriate experience.  The lawyer will come up with reasonable suggestions for the disputed areas and make sure the contract is tight enough to avoid litigation.